# Hibernate @SubSelect equivalent for Spring Data JPQL

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm trying to convert a native query into JPQL. In the native query there's a subquery in from clause. Something like below

```
select * from table1 join (select * from table2) on ...
```

Since I wasn't able to write the same in JPQL, as it doesn't allow subqueries in `from clause`, I have created another entity class which is annotated with hibernate `@SubSelect("select * from table2")`. Now I'm able to use this entity in the `from` clause of the above query in place of subquery.

However there are 2 things that are not quite right

1. `@SubSelect` is not working with JPQL query, so I have to put native query.
2. `@SubSelect` is a hibernate specific annotation and I'm trying to avoid hibernate specific packages.

Is there a `@SubSelect` equivalent for `JPQL`?

Any hint is appreciated.